# something is adding a span to my html and I'm not sure what

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using NodeJS, my package.json has express, jquery, and node-sass as dependencies, and within my code I'm only importing / requiring jQuery.

For some reason, when my index.html file is served, it has the line

`<span id="warning-container"><i data-reactroot=""></i></span>`

I don't see what's doing this manipulation or why. I'm inclined to believe it's something with express, bit I've yet to find any information about this online.

Any idea what adds that line, what said line is doing, and how I can get rid of it if I don't need it?

Comment: Do have any extensions on your browser that might do it?

Comment: Ar you using `<React.Fragment>` in your code?

Comment: I am not, to my knowledge, using anything involving React. My only dependencies are those listed in the description.

Comment: @HagaiWild it's possible that it's some browser extension. I'll investigate this further

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that the extension [Web Of Trust](https://www.mywot.com/) is adding this exact span. WOT is a nice protection tool but when it messes up the code in the code inspector.
WOT is a good protection but as I don't want extensions messing up the HTML of the sites I'm visiting, I've removed it. And reported WOT for doing this bad thing.
Funny thing... I've noticed that when I type some word in the address bar of Chrome then I would see the Google search page plus a text above it suggesting: Did you mean to go to http://word? or something similar. That's where this extension uses it for and it's extremely annoying...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using React/client library ?

React version 0.15.0-alpha.1, there's default data-reactroot attribute on root node.

Comment: I am not, to my knowledge, using anything involving React. My only dependencies are those listed in the description.